# List of strings get one item distinct

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, repeater

i have bind list to repeater (asp.net)

it shows like this

[image]

i want to bind like this

[image]

**My Code**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RptID" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%# Eval("T") %> :</td>
            <td><%# Eval("D") %> :</td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**C#**

```
List<Options> pList = List Type of options;
RptID.DataSource = pList;
RptID.DataBind();
```

**Data Source**

```
public class Options
{
    public string T { get; set; }
    public string D { get; set; }
}
```

How to do this?

Comment: Please add your code, then we can assist you

Comment: since the problem is in the code behind the image, it would be adviseable to show us the code, so we can identify the problem

Comment: @user65439  i have added the code

Comment: what's your DataSource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the `ItemDataBound` event to the Repeater first. Then add a ternary operator that will evaluate the global string `previousValue`, that has the previous value of `T`.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RptID" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RptID_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%# previousValue != Eval("T").ToString() ? Eval("T") + ":" : "" %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("D") %></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Then in code behind add the OntItemDataBound method and the global variable.

```
public string previousValue = "";

protected void RptID_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    //cast the item back to a datarowview
    DataRowView item = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;

    //assign the new value to the global string
    previousValue = item["T"].ToString();
}
```

Or if you bind a `List<class>`, you need to do this:

```
protected void RptID_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    //cast the item back to its class
    Options item = e.Item.DataItem as Options;

    //assign the new value to the global string
    previousValue = item.T;
}
```

Comment: "item" Exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Updated my answer. I forgot you bind a List, not a DataTable or database table. Then you have to cast the `e.Item.DataItem` to its class